# Stream a file from S3 to a HTTP multipart endpoint

Tags: python, python-requests, boto3

I'm trying to stream a large file from an S3 bucket to an HTTP API. I read a lot of SO threads partially covering my needs but was not capable of putting things together.

Reading the file locally is working using request toolbelt:

```
stream = open('/tmp/file', 'rb')
encoder = MultipartEncoder(
    {'attachments': ('file', stream, 'application/octet-stream'), 'canRename': 'true'}
)
headers['Content-Type'] = encoder.content_type
r = requests.post(f'/api/attachments', data=encoder, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

But reading the stream from S3 doesn't:

```
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key='key')
stream = obj['Body']
encoder = MultipartEncoder(
    {'attachments': ('file', stream, 'application/octet-stream'), 'canRename': 'true'}
)
headers['Content-Type'] = encoder.content_type
r = requests.post(f'/api/attachments', data=encoder, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

> self = <requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder.FileWrapper object at 0x1004d4f10>
>
> return total_len(self.fd) - self.fd.tell()
>
> E TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'

I also tried to wrap the stream with different types but no luck:

```
stream = StreamingIterator(obj['ContentLength'], obj['Body']) # transfers data but hangs forever
stream = io.BufferedReader(obj['Body']._raw_stream, obj['ContentLength']) # makes encoder.CustomBytesIO fail on total length calculation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following a lot of false tracks, I finally narrowed the issue down to the multipart encapsulation. I just need to add the multipart at the beginning and the end of the stream:

```
class MultipartEncoder(object):

    def __init__(self, stream, size, filename='file', fieldname='file', filetype=None, boundary=None):
        self.size = int(size)
        self.stream = stream
        self.filename = filename
        self.fieldname = fieldname
        self.filetype = filetype or 'application/octet-stream'
        self.boundary = boundary or '0'*8
        self.offset = 0

    @property
    def content_type(self):
        return f'multipart/form-data; boundary={self.boundary}'

    @property
    def header(self):
        return (
            f'--{self.boundary}\r\n'
            f'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{self.fieldname}"; filename="{self.filename}"\r\n'
            f'Content-Type: {self.filetype}\r\n\r\n'
        ).encode()

    @property
    def footer(self):
        return f'\r\n--{self.boundary}--\r\n'.encode()

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size + len(self.header) + len(self.footer)

    def read(self, size=-1):
        if not self.offset:
            chunk = self.header + self.stream.read(size - len(self.header))
        else:
            chunk = self.stream.read(size)
            if chunk == b'':
                if self.offset < len(self):
                    chunk = self.footer
                else:
                    return b''
        self.offset += len(chunk)
        return chunk


encoder = MultipartEncoder(stream = obj['Body'], size = obj['ContentLength'])
requests.post(url, data=encoder, headers={'Content-Type': encoder.content_type})
```

This is not bullet proof though. It still requires to handle cases where the header is bigger than the size requested. But requests asks for 8192 which is fine for the demonstration.